# Find and replace in shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

Is it possible to search in a file using shell and then replace a value? When I install a service I would like to be able to search out a variable in a config file and then replace/insert my own settings in that value.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Sure, you can do this using sed or awk. sed example:

```
sed -i 's/Andrew/James/g' /home/oleksandr/names.txt
```

Comment: Could you also please explain the command? also maybe give a reference to what sed means? and -i and s and g?

Comment: @Daniel, sed mean stream editor, it is a utility to process text in linux. You can find out more about it by look at the man page with command `man sed` in linux. -i mean do replace inplace, s mean search and replace action, g mean do it globally (not once). Hope that it help

Answer (score 12):

You can use sed to perform search/replace. I usually do this from a bash shell script, and  move the original file containing values to be substituted to a new name, and run sed writing the output to my original file name like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mv myfile.txt myfile.txt.in

sed -e 's/PatternToBeReplaced/Replacement/g' myfile.txt.in > myfile.txt.
```

If you don't specify an output, the replacement will go to stdout.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i 's/variable/replacement/g' *.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed to do this:

```
sed -i 's/toreplace/yoursetting/' configfile
```

sed is probably available on every unix like system out there. If you want to replace more than one occurence you can add a g to the s-command:

```
sed -i 's/toreplace/yoursetting/g' configfile
```

Be careful since this can completely destroy your configfile if you don't specify your toreplace-value correctly. sed also supports regular expressions in searching and replacing.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [UNIX power tools](https://www.google.bg/search?q=UNIX%20power%20tools) **awk, sed, grep** and [in-place edit of files](http://www.unixguide.net/unix/perl_oneliners.shtml) with Perl.

Answer (score 1):

```
filepath="/var/start/system/dir1"
searchstring="test"
replacestring="test01"

i=0; 

for file in $(grep -l -R $searchstring $filepath)
do
  cp $file $file.bak
  sed -e "s/$searchstring/$replacestring/ig" $file > tempfile.tmp
  mv tempfile.tmp $file

  let i++;

  echo "Modified: " $file
done
```

Comment: Could you check the `enter code here` in your code? It probably should not be there. By the way: In most cases it's a good idea to supply comments in your solution or at least to summarize the approach that you chose tackle the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Generally a tool like awk or sed are used for this.

```
$ sed -i 's/ugly/beautiful/g' /home/bruno/old-friends/sue.txt
```