# Installing meteor launch script to home directory

Tags: javascript, meteor

When installing meteor using `curl install.meteor.com | sh`, it tries to install a launcher script at `/usr/local/bin/meteor`. However, that requires me to supply an administrator password, which I cannot supply when trying to automate application deployment. in the script at install.meteor.com, there's a line here:

```
PREFIX="/usr/local"
```

I'd really like to change the PREFIX variable to "~/local", so that I can install this executable within my home directory and add the directory to my PATH variable. Is there a way to change this variable by sending a runtime variable without downloading the file and editing it myself? I understand that I could just use $HOME/.meteor/tools/latest/launch-meteor to launch my meteor application, but I'd prefer using the launch script instead.

Answer (score 2):

Short and sweet:

```
curl install.meteor.com | sed -e 's/PREFIX="\/usr\/local"/PREFIX="\/~\/local"/g' | sh
```

With props to https://stackoverflow.com/a/10858043/223225. (Caveat: I've only tested this as `curl install.meteor.com | sed -e 's/PREFIX="\/usr\/local"/PREFIX="\/~\/local"/g' | cat` rather than `| sh` because I don't want to reinstall Meteor on my system at the moment, but I would be surprised if `| sh` didn't also work.)